# Help with understanding orientation for vector surfaces

Tags: vector-analysis, orientation

Can someone help me understand orientation for vector surfaces?

From researching orientation for vector surfaces, I believe that, for CLOSED SURFACES, the upward orientation would be the side pointing away from the enclosed region, while downward would point towards the enclosed region.

However, I seem to be having problems finding information that I can understand about vector surfaces that are not closed.

Let's take a hemisphere: $z = \sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}$ as an example.

From what I think, the upwards orientation would be pointing away from the "outer" top of the hemisphere, while the downwards orientation would be pointing down from the "inner" bottom of the hemisphere.

Even though, I say this, I'm not sure whether this is actually true or more importantly WHY it would be true (if so). I'm just assuming because of the terms "upward" and "downward" which is quite faulty logic.

Comment: It's entirely arbitrary: vector surfaces (or, more generally, orientable manifolds) have two orientations. What you choose to call those two orientations is pretty much entirely up to you.

Comment: @user3482749 Oh...my professor said if you do surface integrals based on the wrong orientation, you would get a negative value, so I thought there was a more specific meaning to it.

Comment: Yes, flipping the orientation flips the sign of basically everything. That's just not a particular problem.

Comment: The orientation must be given as part of the description of the surface over which you’re integrating. There may well be a convention in force in your course so that it need not be stated explicitly every time.